# Как запретить редактировать параметры GRUB "на лету"?

Tags: linux, grub, защита

Есть мысль убрать возможность редактирования cmdline в GRUB посредством полного отключения опции командной строки (или хотя бы меню редактирования) через установку пароля. Видел вариант такой (что дописать в 00_header):

```
set superusers="root"
password_pbkdf2 root grub.pbkdf2.sha512.password
export superusers
```

И такой:

```
set superusers="root"
password root rootpassword
export superusers
```

Оба не работают:

```
root@linuxlite6:/ # update-grub
/etc/grub.d/00_header: 451: password: command not found
root@linuxlite6:/ # update-grub
/etc/grub.d/00_header: 451: password_pbkdf2: command not found
```

И да, не говорите про GRUB_TIMEOUT="0" и GRUB_HIDDEN=true. Они просто убирают меню выбора, но мне нужно не это. Мне нужно просто отключить/ограничить доступ к командной строке GRUB (в т ч редактированию опций загрузки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не ломай 00_header создай новый файл 00_passwords

Эти не ставятся в граб на прямую. Они должны вывести текст втавки.

```
#! /bin/sh
set -e

cat << EOF
set superusers="root"
password root rootpassword
export superusers
EOF
```

И пролистай остальные файлы, посмотри не перетирается ли superusers другим способом

Comment: Пароль-то спрашивает, только вот меню выбора пропало, сразу грузит систему.

Comment: А надо, чтобы пароль спрашивался строго при попытке доступа в командную строку/редактор cmdline (кнопка e в GRUB)

Comment: я только написал что у вас не так) пароль на e не ставил.... ну точнее ставил, но  в астре и там оно по умолчанию)

Comment: А вот если заменить password на password_pbkdf2, то все работаеь